# document.location modifies WebApi route when trying to download file

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I have an application built with AngularJs and WebApi. I'm trying to download a file when a button is pressed. This is the code for ng-click:

```
                $scope.download = function (documentObj) {
                if (documentObj && documentObj.FileName)
                {
                    var urlParams = "sId=" + documentObj.IdStudy + "&fId=" + documentObj.IdRequiredFile + "&fName=" + documentObj.FileName;

                    document.location = "api/document/download?" + urlParams;
                }
            };
```

This is working well in Chrome and Mozilla but not in IE. In any IE. 
I have noticed that the URL for the WebApi is very different in IE after running this code. More specifically:

The view i'm working in has this URL: http://localhost:54094/admin/studies/edit/1
After I call the ng-click function that should start the download I see the following results:

- Chrome:http://localhost:54094/api/document/download?sId=71&fId=4&fName=Basis%20KHT%202016.sql
- IE:http://localhost:54094/admin/studies/edit/api/document/download?sId=71&fId=4&fName=Basis KHT 2016.sql

Thus, in IE, the correct WebApi service is not called.

What am I missing or not doing right? Any tips would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should use absolute path not a relative one...just add a `/`

```
document.location = "/api/document/download?" + urlParams;
```

Browser will look for `api` directory in root of site assuming you have not used a `<base>` tag in page